# Application works fine in weblogic 10.3.5 but gives following errors in weblogic 10.3.0:

Tags: nullpointerexception, el, weblogic-10.x, apache-commons-digester

Dec 1, 2014 6:24:02 AM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error

```
SEVERE: Parse Error at line 36 column 17: 
The content of element type "struts-config" must match "(display-name?,description?,data-sources?,form-beans?,global-exceptions?,
global-forwards?,action-mappings?,controller?,message-resources*,plug-in*)".

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "struts-config" must match 
"(display-name?,description?,data-sources?,form-beans?,global-exceptions?,global-forwards?,
action-mappings?,controller?,message-resources*,plug-in*)".

at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
```

---

```
WARNING: #{report_MB.onLoad}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{report_MB.onLoad}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

---

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Can anybody help pls... :(

Comment: Post your struts-config.xml file. 10.3.5 may be using a different schema/DTD than 10.3.